# In the new MacOS 13 chat.db, where is the text from edited messages stored?

Tags: macos, imessage

We have an app that analyzes the iMessage chat.db for backup, but edited and deleted messages seem to have NULL as their text value. I can understand deleted messages, but why would edited messages have NULL? Their text needs to be stored somewhere. Has anyone got any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Even weirder, what I'm seeing is that even regular non-edited messages don't have their `text` column populated. I just posted that more general question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72817995/text-no-longer-populated-in-messages-chat-db-database-in-macos-13-ventura

Comment: It seems that after syncing with iCloud (if iCloud Messages is enabled), the text column is nulled out and it goes into attributedBody. Maybe that's the new way of representing things?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but the text can be found in the "attributedBody" field. It is wrapped inside a NSString object, so you need some decoding to get it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community This answer was helpful to me as-is.