# How to decode message_summary_info in macOS Messages chat.db

Tags: python, macos, imessage

In the chat.db Messages database on macOS, in the `message` table there exist two binary blob columns:

- `attributedBody`
- `message_summary_info`

The message edit history (introduced with macOS Ventura) is stored in the `message_summary_info`.

I'm able to decode and parse the `attributedBody` with [python-typedstream](https://github.com/dgelessus/python-typedstream), however attempting to do so on the `message_summary_info` yields an error `typedstream.stream.InvalidTypedStreamError: Invalid streamer version: 98`.

How can I decode and parse `message_summary_info`?

(Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646565/in-the-new-macos-13-chat-db-where-is-the-text-from-edited-messages-stored))

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you decoded attributedBody using python-typedstream? I've had no luck so far. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found at least a partial solution with python leveraging [plistlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html) since the `message_summary_info` is a binary plist, but I'm open to better solutions if they exist.

Here is some output of some test messages I sent with macOS Messages and edited. The message was originally "Test BEFORE edit", then was edited to "Test AFTER edit", then was edited once more to "Test AFTER edit 2".

```
>>> import plistlib
>>> pprint(plistlib.loads(bytes_str))
{'ec': {'0': [{'d': 690916194.2870002,
               't': b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x12N'
                    b'SAttributedString\x00\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x00\x85\x92'
                    b'\x84\x84\x84\x08NSString\x01\x94\x84\x01+\x10Test BEFOR'
                    b'E edit\x86\x84\x02iI\x01\x10\x92\x84\x84\x84\x0cNSDict'
                    b'ionary\x00\x94\x84\x01i\x01\x92\x84\x96\x96\x1d__kIMMe'
                    b'ssagePartAttributeName\x86\x92\x84\x84\x84\x08NSNumber'
                    b'\x00\x84\x84\x07NSValue\x00\x94\x84\x01*\x84\x99\x99\x00'
                    b'\x86\x86\x86'},
              {'bcg': '5BE7ACC0-8863-4418-A966-1320577ED52F',
               'd': 690916202.619842,
               't': b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x12N'
                    b'SAttributedString\x00\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x00\x85\x92'
                    b'\x84\x84\x84\x08NSString\x01\x94\x84\x01+\x0fTest AFTER'
                    b' edit\x86\x84\x02iI\x01\x0f\x92\x84\x84\x84\x0cNSDicti'
                    b'onary\x00\x94\x84\x01i\x01\x92\x84\x96\x96\x1d__kIMMes'
                    b'sagePartAttributeName\x86\x92\x84\x84\x84\x08NSNumber\x00'
                    b'\x84\x84\x07NSValue\x00\x94\x84\x01*\x84\x99\x99\x00\x86'
                    b'\x86\x86'},
              {'bcg': '98E04B01-7490-4984-92D5-5910C24F51C1',
               'd': 690916210.155562,
               't': b'\x04\x0bstreamtyped\x81\xe8\x03\x84\x01@\x84\x84\x84\x12N'
                    b'SAttributedString\x00\x84\x84\x08NSObject\x00\x85\x92'
                    b'\x84\x84\x84\x08NSString\x01\x94\x84\x01+\x11Test AFTER'
                    b' edit 2\x86\x84\x02iI\x01\x11\x92\x84\x84\x84\x0cNSDic'
                    b'tionary\x00\x94\x84\x01i\x01\x92\x84\x96\x96\x1d__kIMM'
                    b'essagePartAttributeName\x86\x92\x84\x84\x84\x08NSNumbe'
                    b'r\x00\x84\x84\x07NSValue\x00\x94\x84\x01*\x84\x99\x99'
                    b'\x00\x86\x86\x86'}]},
 'ep': [0],
 'euh': ['RECIPIENT@icloud.com'],
 'otr': {'0': {'le': 16, 'lo': 0}},
 'ust': True}
```